# Query error in MongoDB after Sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I write query

```
db.collectionX.find()
```

to find all documents in a sharded collectionX, it gives :

```
 error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Retried 10 times without successfully establishing shard version.",
    "code" : 63,
    "codeName" : "StaleShardVersion"
}
```

Please find me out the error or the way to solve this problem !

Answer (score 0):

Are you changed mongo shard config or shard collection config?

try print mongos logs and determine your `Balancer` Refreshing chunks was

completed.